# How do I Select Rows in DataTable based on Name and Date in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, select, type-conversion

Trying to create a VB.net expression to select rows from a datatable that only have a certain vendor's name (Vendor column), and the event is after a certain date (PurchaseDate column).

My current approach is to use:

```
datatableVar.Select("Vendor = '" + vendorName.ToString + "' And PurchaseDate < Convert('" + eventDate.ToString + "', DateTime)")
```

Currently it is saying that DateTime is an invalid Type name, pretty sure this is the syntax for convert though and it takes DateTime as a thing to format to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option depends on exactly what you want to do with the data afterwards but, assuming that you want to stick with that `Select` method, there's no need to call `Convert` because you can just use a `DateTime` literal:

```
datatableVar.Select($"Vendor = '{vendorName}' AND PurchaseDate < #{eventDate:M/dd/yyyy}#")
```

Note that I have also used string interpolation rather than concatenation, in order to aid readability.  If you're using an earlier version than VB 2015, use `String.Format` instead:

```
datatableVar.Select(String.Format("Vendor = '{0}' AND PurchaseDate < #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#",
                                  vendorName,
                                  eventDate)
```

The reason that your original code didn't work is that you didn't do what the documentation tells you to do when calling `Convert`.  The example in the documentation is this:

```
myDataColumn.Expression = "Convert(total, 'System.Int32')"
```

So you can see there that the type is qualified with the namespace and it is wrapped in single quotes.  That means that:

```
"', DateTime)")
```

should have been:

```
"', 'System.DateTime')")
```

**ALWAYS** read the relevant documentation first.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll implement it and let you know if it works. I tried finding the documentation, couldn't as I tried to look up filterExpression types and didn't get anything to do with Convert and thought that the syntax was different to VB.net given it is parsed as a string. What language is the string actually in?

Comment: The documentation for the `DataTable.Select` method provides two relevant links. The first one leads to examples [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/). That code is for C# but the actual filter expressions aren't C# or VB, so those parts are exactly the same. The other leads to a full description of supported syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression). What's supported is a subset of SQL specific to ADO.NET, probably based on Jet SQL.

Comment: Second solution in answer worked as outdated VB.net must be being used.